# Getting crash on android 23.0.1

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I tested this code on an emulator which has android marshmallow, there is no crash on emulator . I can't see logcat error because i am sending debug apk to my friend and he is telling me there is a crash . Can you guys guess whats the problem. its simple two lines code. crash happens on button click and code inside it is here....

```
       if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23){
            if(checkSelfPermission(
                    Manifest.permission.READ_SMS)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(
                    Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

                prepareSend();

            }else  {
                if (!shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(
                        Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {

                    requestPermissions(
                            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_SMS, Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS},
                        1);
                }}
            }else{

                prepareSend();
            }
```

Other code is fine here is prepare send there are no crashes on devices lower than 23.

```
          public void prepareSend() {
        String phones = extractPhones();
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(phones) || TextUtils.isEmpty(messageText.getText().toString()) || TextUtils.isEmpty(bomb.getText().toString()) || TextUtils.isEmpty(delay.getText().toString()))
            Toast.makeText(this,"One or more required field is empty.",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else {
            //Toast.makeText(this,phones,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),FreshService.class);
            intent.putExtra("message",messageText.getText().toString().trim());
            intent.putExtra("bombs",Integer.parseInt(bomb.getText().toString()));
            int delayLong = Integer.parseInt(delay.getText().toString());
            intent.putExtra("interval",delayLong);
            intent.putExtra("phones", phones);

            startService(intent);
            //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Service started successfully interval:" + delayLong,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            btnSend.setEnabled(false);
            btnStop.setEnabled(true);
            doBindService();
        }

}
```

Comment: Don't EVER use `getBaseContext()` unless you know what you're doing. That stack trace would help, until you get it, don't expect much help.

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(bomb.getText().toString())` this will crash if the input box is empty. Same for `delay`.

Comment: No it doesnt @EugenPechanec for some reason it gives a toast .